# Can't build camera driver for MacAir on Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: drivers, kernel, compiling, camera

I followed the recommended way to install the driver for the camera on my MacAir running Ubuntu 21.10:

```
sudo apt-get install git
sudo apt-get install curl xzcat cpio
git clone https://github.com/patjak/facetimehd-firmware.git
cd facetimehd-firmware
make
sudo make install
cd ..
sudo apt-get install kmod libssl-dev checkinstall
git clone https://github.com/patjak/bcwc_pcie.git
cd bcwc_pcie
make
sudo make install
sudo depmod
sudo modprobe -r bdc_pci
sudo modprobe facetimehd
sudo nano /etc/modules
```

Added the line `facetimehd`, write and close.

But when I started building the driver, I got:

```
skipping BTF generation for facetimehd.ko due to unavailability of vmlinux
```

I looked for vmlinux which was not to be found on my system.  I understand that it is extracted from vmlinuz (in `/boot`).

I am not sure how to get vmlinux for my kernel `linux-headers-5.13.0-25-generic`. How do I extract from vmlinuz, and where do I put it to be able to build the facetimehd.ko?

Comment: I don't believe this is an error. I believe that the facetimehd.ko is built and installed nonetheless. Are there any errors when you modprobe the driver?

Comment: You are right. I panicked - I finished the sequence of the commands and after reboot I could see myself in cheese.  The quality of the video is low but this is different problem.  Thanks for your help.